# Yii2: Enabling cookies in Rest application

Tags: yii2

I have a headless application written in yii, with an Angular application using the yii2 api. Currently im using local storage for tokens, but I read this [link](https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage) and would like to store the token in a cookie.

**Auth action:**

```
\Yii::$app->response->cookies->add(new Cookie([
    'name' => 'token',
    'value'=> $token->__toString()
]));
```

**AuthMethod:**

```
if (($cookie = $cookies->get('token')) !== null) {
    die('Token found in cookie');
    $token = $parser->parse($cookie->value);
}
```

The token is allways `null`, so it seems like cookies are disabled by default in Rest controllers / JSON responses, how can I enable this?

**For furture reference, if the link is dead** it concludes that cookies are better than local storage for JWT tokens

> Cookies, when used with the HttpOnly cookie flag, are not accessible through JavaScript, and are immune to XSS. You can also set the Secure cookie flag to guarantee the cookie is only sent over HTTPS. This is one of the main reasons that cookies have been leveraged in the past to store tokens or session data. Modern developers are hesitant to use cookies because they traditionally required state to be stored on the server, thus breaking RESTful best practices. Cookies as a storage mechanism do not require state to be stored on the server if you are storing a JWT in the cookie. This is because the JWT encapsulates everything the server needs to serve the request.

**EDIT**

Using the native PHP $_COOKIE the cookie can be read by the yii2 application, but the setcookie() does not work. It looks like the yii2-rest controller strips away the headers before sending the response.

Comment: You are using Angularjs «1.6.x» or Angular «2,4» ?
The solution is in both Angular and on your API, so the second question, Are you using YII2 APi?

Comment: Please comment about the versions you use on angular, and Yii2. With that maybe I will have an answer.

Comment: Also, can you please comment on how are you managing JWT inside YII2, are you using an Extension?

Comment: I have an idea of what is the problem, but please let me know a bit more of the architecture.

Comment: The Angular version is irrelevant, I'm currently testing only using the API and POSTman, Yii version is 2.0.6 and the JWT's are handled with lcobucci/jwt package and some custom code. Regardless, I've tried using native PHP cookies, and the headers are still stripped by the framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will make my first attempt to answer and I hope it makes sense and helps you and others.

I asked you about angular version, because, as you know angular works as a one page app, and I will need proof of concept code to show my point «I will asume angularjs 1.6.x», it means it works away from your YII2, unless you are rendering angular on call. Now there are two ways to “bypass” this in order to set up the cookie. 
The first one will be to set up your cookie inside angular, on your controller call your login endpoint and make it return the token (in my example I am not doing that part just for speed). And then build the cookie using the $cookie service «you will have to import angular-cookie».
The other way could be to call and endpoint inside Yii «look at the actionSetCookie example» and build the cookie inside it, I don't like that one that much looks dirty to me.

Now here comes the big problem, you may have, yii uses a cookie validation that “signs the cookie”, but when you build the cookie outside, this cookie will not work. So… to make this example work you will have to turn off cookie validation.

```
components' => [
  'request' => [
    'enableCookieValidation' => false, //<---make it false
    'enableCsrfValidation' => true,
    'cookieValidationKey' => 'hdfghdsrthrgfdhfghthdrtth',
    'parsers' => [
      'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
    ]
  ],
    ...
]
```

Now, I made a working test.
First I made two simple action to test that I was actually building the cookie. And that I was able to call them with postman.

```
public function actionSetCookie()
{
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    $session = Yii::$app->session;
    $cookies_rsp = Yii::$app->response->cookies;
    $cookies_rsp->add(new Cookie([
        'name' => 'token',
        'value' => 'tt-eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIs...',
    ]));
    $response = ['cookie set'=>$cookies_rsp];
    return $response;
}

public function actionCookie()
{
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    $session = Yii::$app->session;
    $cookies = Yii::$app->request->cookies;
    $token = '';
    if (isset($cookies['token'])) {
        $token = $cookies['token']->value;
    }
    $response = ['token'=>$token];
    return $response;
}
```

And I made two controllers in angular to make the explanation:

```
.controller('View1Ctrl', ['$cookies', function ($cookies) {
    console.log('View1Ctrl++++++++');
    var vm = this;
    vm.title = 'Customers';
    $cookies.remove('token');
    $cookies.put('token', 'my-angular-token');
    vm.myToken = $cookies.get('token');
    console.log('myToken', vm.myToken);
}

.controller('View2Ctrl', ['$http', function ($http) {
    console.log('View2Ctrl');
    //Lest set the cookie
    $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://test.dev/site/set-cookie'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        console.log('response', response);
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.error('err', response)
    });
}
```

**Now here it goes**

On solution 1 «View1Ctrl», I build the cookie using the $cookie service, and I can validate it using action actionCookie, this will be read only if enableCookieValidation is false.

On the solution 2 «View2Ctrl», I am using the actionSetCookie as a http get endpoint that does not much, but sets the cookie, this cookie will work with  enableCookieValidation false or true.

**Conclusión**
Remember that angular and yii2 are "supposed" to be agnostic and independent, so you will have to consume yii as endpoint.

You will have to se the enableCookieValidation, depending on your solution. I am not sure if there is a way to do it with angular but probably is not a good idea because you will have to publish the cookieValidationKey inside angular.

I don't like using cookies for apis, personally, because the idea of stateless and cookieless will help if your are developing a mobile app «I might be wrong about that».

About postman, it will work with solution 2 unless you turn off enableCookieValidation. Remember that this validation will add some salt to the token inside a cookie, that is yii additional security.
Finally on p[ostman, if enableCookieValidation is set to true and toy are manually making the cookie, Yii will not receive the cookie, because of security.

[image]

Just to illustrate this security related to the signing of cookies, I captured this video. I hope this will help. So this is because CookieValidation is true. This is a reason no to use the PHP default cookie service but tu use the one that Yii provides. On the video you will see how this system very specific for each cookie. ANd why you may not see the cookie in postman.

If you make CookieValidation false, this manual cookies, php default cookies will actually work again, but is less secure.

[Video](https://youtu.be/QIKl_JCjMB4)

About the discussion on the blog and Angular, remember that angular actually protects your app when using $http calls, it is very secure in that sense, but also don't forget to use ngSanitize on your app.
More on this:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#cross-site-request-forgery-xsrf-protection
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies

Finally, if I find something on securing the cookie like Yii2 does from angular I will add that to the post.

Hope it helps.

Just in case you like to look at my code

https://github.com/moplin/testdev

Comment: This actually boiled down to a POSTman issue I believe. I still can't get the cookie in the postman "cookies"-tab, but the two functions you provided did actually work. I did not even think to test that, and the code has probably worked all along. Thank you for your comprehensive answer.

Comment: Thanks. I do recommend you to play with enableCookieValidation configuration, I am sure that is the key to use postman. Because Yii cookie management is very secure and will no read cookies without the proper key (image).

Comment: SO, I made a small video that kinds of explains the cookie validation and how it affects the reading of the cookie. [video](https://youtu.be/QIKl_JCjMB4)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access cookies on server side so you have to send them as well in your request. Angular by default does not send cookies in XHR request. To enable cookies in request add this following code:

```
.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;

});
```

OR

```
$http.get("URL", { withCredentials: true })
  .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {})
  .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {});
```

See Usage section in angular [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Make sure you also setting that cookie on client side, using javascript and then check in your chrome console for http request making sure it's also sending cookie in it.

Make sure you read cookies from `$cookies = Yii::$app->request->cookies;`
 http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-sessions-cookies.html#reading-cookies

And writing a cookie using `$cookies = Yii::$app->response->cookies;`
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-sessions-cookies.html#sending-cookies

Comment: I'm working with POSTman plugin in chrome, and the cookie is not returned in the response. Haven't even tried with the front-end app yet.

Comment: @Jørgen make sure you read cookie from `Yii::$app->request->cookies;` and write using `Yii::$app->response->cookies;`

Comment: Yeah. I know. I've double checked that.

Comment: May be `session` is disabled in Rest Controller: see https://nix-tips.ru/yii2-api-guides/guide-en-rest-authentication.html and https://nix-tips.ru/yii2-api-guides/yii-web-user.html#$enableSession-detai

Comment: Sessions are enabled. That should not kill cookies anyway, should it?

Answer (score 0):

If the token is an access token you could you use in REST controller
the autheticator behaviors

```
yii\filters\auth\HttpBasicAuth;
yii\filters\auth\HttpBearerAuth;
yii\filters\auth\QueryParamAuth;
```

and when received first time token to save it to a cookie in the browser from angular